# jq specify default value for some situation

Tags: default-value, jq

Now I have a json

```
[
  {
    "city": "SH",
    "age": 0,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "city": "SH",
    "age": 20,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "city": "SH",
    "age": 40,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "city": "BJ",
    "age": 20,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "city": "BJ",
    "age": 30,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Now I want to get the count array of every age for some data visualization purpose(see [demo](http://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xSk1tZenM-&v=3)). e.g

```
# age data: [shCount, bjCount]
age: 0, data:[1, 0]
age: 20, data: [1, 2] 
age: 30, data: [0, 1]
age: 40, data: [1, 0]
```

If the city does not have the age, give a default value 0. But if the city does not have the age, it will have not the related json object.

So I cannot just by using below shell to get count array of every age, e.g

```
# without BJ value
➜  ~ jq -c '.[] | select(.age==0) | [.city, .count]' foo.json
["SH",1]

➜  ~ jq -c '.[] | select(.age==20) | [.city, .count]' foo.json
["SH",1]
["BJ",2]
```

So if age is 0, how to specify a default value of 0 to `BJ`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relevant city names are not know beforehand, then the following approach has much to recommend it if the city names are strings:

```
# Merge records having the same age
def merge:
  reduce .[] as $x ({}; . + ($x | { (.city) : .count}) );

# Create an object holding the default values:
def zeros:
  map( {(tostring): 0} ) | add;

group_by(.age)
| map( {age: .[0].age, data: merge} )
| (map(.data) | add | keys | zeros) as $zeros
| map( .data = $zeros + .data )
```

The output of the above is an array of objects having the form:
    {"age": _, "data": CITIES}

e.g.

```
 {
    "age": 40,
    "data": {
      "BJ": 0,
      "SH": 1
    }
  }
```

It is now easy to transmogrify CITIES to the desired format.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, a helper function for merging same-age records is useful. This is where the default values are defined:

```
def merge:
  reduce .[] as $x ([0,0];
    if $x.city == "SH" then .[0] = $x.count else .[1] = $x.count end);
```

Next, we have only to group records by age:

```
group_by(.age)
| map( {age: .[0].age, data: merge} )
```

Invocation:

```
jq -c -f program.jq input.json
```

Result:

```
[{"age":0,"data":[1,0]},{"age":20,"data":[1,2]},{"age":30,"data":[0,1]},{"age":40,"data":[1,0]}]
```

You can then format the result in whichever way you want.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get the result as you but with the error message: `jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot iterate over null (null)`.  In addition what about there are many cities?

Comment: You will probably want to invoke jq without the -n option. I've updated the answer accordingly. As for handling multiple cities, I've added another answer.